# Socket.io chat app on heroku with node.js

Tags: node.js, heroku, socket.io

Messing about with Node.js and a bit nonplussed that I can't get something this simple working.  This code works fine on my local server, but the chat doesn't work on Heroku.  If I enter something, nothing happens.  I've checked the Heroku logs and they look fine.

**package.json**

```
{
     "name": "mukhin_chat",
     "description": "example chat application with socket.io",
     "version": "0.0.1",
     "dependencies": {
        "express": "2.4.6",
        "socket.io": "0.8.4"
     },
    "engines": {
    "node": "0.8.x",
    "npm": "1.1.x"
  }
}
```

**app.js**

```
// Variable port setting for heroku

var port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

var app = require('express').createServer()
var io = require('socket.io').listen(app);

app.listen(port);

// Heroku setting for long polling - assuming io is the Socket.IO server object
io.configure(function () { 
  io.set("transports", ["xhr-polling"]); 
  io.set("polling duration", 10); 
});

// routing
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.sendfile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

// usernames which are currently connected to the chat
var usernames = {};

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {

    // when the client emits 'sendchat', this listens and executes
    socket.on('sendchat', function (data) {
        // we tell the client to execute 'updatechat' with 2 parameters
        io.sockets.emit('updatechat', socket.username, data);
    });

    // when the client emits 'adduser', this listens and executes
    socket.on('adduser', function(username){
        // we store the username in the socket session for this client
        socket.username = username;
        // add the client's username to the global list
        usernames[username] = username;
        // echo to client they've connected
        socket.emit('updatechat', 'SERVER', 'you have connected');
        // echo globally (all clients) that a person has connected
        socket.broadcast.emit('updatechat', 'SERVER', username + ' has connected');
        // update the list of users in chat, client-side
        io.sockets.emit('updateusers', usernames);
    });

    // when the user disconnects.. perform this
    socket.on('disconnect', function(){
        // remove the username from global usernames list
        delete usernames[socket.username];
        // update list of users in chat, client-side
        io.sockets.emit('updateusers', usernames);
        // echo globally that this client has left
        socket.broadcast.emit('updatechat', 'SERVER', socket.username + ' has disconnected');
    });
});
```

**index.html**

```
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:8080');

    // on connection to server, ask for user's name with an anonymous callback
    socket.on('connect', function(){
        // call the server-side function 'adduser' and send one parameter (value of prompt)
        socket.emit('adduser', prompt("What's your name?"));
    });

    // listener, whenever the server emits 'updatechat', this updates the chat body
    socket.on('updatechat', function (username, data) {
        $('#conversation').append('<b>'+username + ':</b> ' + data + '<br>');
    });

    // listener, whenever the server emits 'updateusers', this updates the username list
    socket.on('updateusers', function(data) {
        $('#users').empty();
        $.each(data, function(key, value) {
            $('#users').append('<div>' + key + '</div>');
        });
    });

    // on load of page
    $(function(){
        // when the client clicks SEND
        $('#datasend').click( function() {
            var message = $('#data').val();
            $('#data').val('');
            // tell server to execute 'sendchat' and send along one parameter
            socket.emit('sendchat', message);
        });

        // when the client hits ENTER on their keyboard
        $('#data').keypress(function(e) {
            if(e.which == 13) {
                $(this).blur();
                $('#datasend').focus().click();
            }
        });
    });

</script>
<div style="float:left;width:100px;border-right:1px solid black;height:300px;padding:10px;overflow:scroll-y;">
    <b>USERS</b>
    <div id="users"></div>
</div>
<div style="float:left;width:300px;height:250px;overflow:scroll-y;padding:10px;">
    <div id="conversation"></div>
    <input id="data" style="width:200px;" />
    <input type="button" id="datasend" value="send" />
</div>
```

**Procfile**

```
web: node app.js
```

**Logs**

```
2012-08-15T01:24:03+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to starting
2012-08-15T01:24:03+00:00 heroku[slugc]: Slug compilation finished
2012-08-15T01:24:05+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `node app.js`
2012-08-15T01:24:05+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2012-08-15T01:24:07+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2012-08-15T01:24:08+00:00 app[web.1]:    info  - socket.io started
2012-08-15T01:24:09+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2012-08-15T01:24:21+00:00 heroku[router]: GET still-bastion-7144.herokuapp.com/ dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=23ms status=200 bytes=1774
2012-08-15T01:24:21+00:00 app[web.1]:    debug - served static /socket.io.js
2012-08-15T01:24:21+00:00 heroku[router]: GET still-bastion-7144.herokuapp.com/socket.io/socket.io.js dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=15ms status=200 bytes=95997
2012-08-15T01:24:23+00:00 heroku[router]: GET still-bastion-7144.herokuapp.com/favicon.ico dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=3ms status=404 bytes=34
2012-08-15T01:24:45+00:00 heroku[router]: GET still-bastion-7144.herokuapp.com/ dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=7ms status=200 bytes=1774
2012-08-15T01:24:45+00:00 app[web.1]:    debug - served static /socket.io.js
2012-08-15T01:24:45+00:00 heroku[router]: GET still-bastion-7144.herokuapp.com/socket.io/socket.io.js dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=18ms status=200 bytes=95997
2012-08-15T01:24:50+00:00 heroku[router]: GET still-bastion-7144.herokuapp.com/ dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=6ms status=304 bytes=0
2012-08-15T01:24:51+00:00 app[web.1]:    debug - served static /socket.io.js
2012-08-15T01:24:51+00:00 heroku[router]: GET still-bastion-7144.herokuapp.com/socket.io/socket.io.js dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=14ms status=200 bytes=95997
```

Comment: You do know that on Heroku, websockets don't work and socket.io falls back to long polling or heartbeats?

Comment: Yep.  I added the heroku configuration for long polling (line 6 of app.js) - but my understanding is that the chat app should still work, even with that setting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your client code you're trying to connect to port 8080, which is inconsistent with the port your server is listening on.

Comment: You're right.  For anyone else looking at this question, problem solved by changing line 4 of index.html to "   var socket = io.connect();   "  Just had to remove the local port reference.

Answer (score 2):

My chat was perfectly working on local, but when i uploaded it on server it didn't work between different devices. I solved it same way: 
in my index.html i set `var socket = io.connect();` on local it was `io.connect('http://localhost:8081');`
Now it works like charm)))))

Comment: Wow I just lost ~6h of productive dev time to this. I love you and want to give you a big hug.

Answer (score 0):

For the websockets to work on heroku , you must first enable them.

Use this `heroku labs:enable websockets -a yourappname` from the terminal.

Hope this solves the problem.